# Getting the decimal point value

Tags: c++, double

I have a function which should covert a `double` value into `string` one:

```
inline static string StringFromNumber(double val) // suppose val = 34.5678
{
 long integer = (long)val; // integer = 34
 long pointPart; // should be = 5678  how do I get it?
}
```

How do I get a `long` value for both `integer` and `pointPart`?

**Add:** I want a precision of 17 numbers, with discarding the zeros. More examples:

> val = 3.14 integer = 3 pointPart = 14
>
> val = 134.4566425814748 integer = 134 pointPart = 4566425814748

I have not got any solution so far. How can I get it?

Comment: `pointpart = (val - integer) * decimalplacesyouneed`? Oh i see it's a long, how many decimal places you want?

Comment: What should pointPart be for 34.567 and 34.56789? Also, what if val ≥ LONG_MAX + 1?

Comment: Your example and question are bogus. 34.5678 is not exactly representable as a double. Check here: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=34.5678 I presume you don't want to see 56779999999999830606611794792115688323974609375 as the answer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh Oh! I want only 17 numbers after the point.

Comment: `StringFromNumber`? Perhaps you want to check `ostringstream` or `snprintf` or `lexical_cast`.

Comment: Your definition of pointPart doesn't work, because it gives the same value for 3.14, 3.014, 3.0014 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `modf` to separate the integer and fractional parts.  You can then multiply the fractional part by `1.0e17`, and call `floor` to properly round the results to it's  integer component, and then cast to a `unsigned long` (the fractional part will never be negative, and this allows you to maximize the number of bits in the integral type).  Finally run though a loop to trim off the zeros on the `unsigned long`. For instance:

```
inline static string StringFromNumber(double val)
{
    double intpart, fracpart;
    fracpart = round((modf(val, &intpart)) * 1.0e17);

    long int_long = static_cast<long>(intpart);
    unsigned long frac_long = static_cast<long>(fracpart);

    //trim off the zeros
    for(unsigned long divisor = 10;;divisor *= 10)
    {
        if ((frac_long / divisor) * divisor != frac_long)
        {
            frac_long = frac_long / (divisor / 10);
            break;
        }
    }

    //...more code for converting to string
}
```

Note that this code will only work up to 17 decimal places if you are on a 64-bit platform and `unsigned long` is defined as a 64-bit integer-type.  Otherwise you will want to change `unsigned long` to `uint64_t`.  Also keep in mind that since floating point numbers are approximations, and there's a multiplier by `1.0e17`, the value of `fracpart` may not be exactly the value of the point-part of `val` ... in other words there may be some additional digits after any necessary rounding.

Comment: Sorry, there was one syntax-related typo I just fixed.  Other than that, what results were you looking for?  For instance, if I passed in `3.15247428`, I get `3` for the integer portion and `15247428` for the fractional part.  You can see the results here: http://codepad.org/FPAQkWhq ... Please note that since that code is running on a 32-bit platform, I've changed the multiplier to 1.0e8, since anything over 4.2e9 will overflow an `unsigned long` type.

Answer (score 3):

A stringstream won't get you the decimal point in particular, but it will convert the entire number to a string.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << val;
/*access the newly-created string with str()*/
return ss.str();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
long pointPart = static_cast<long>(val*10)%10;
```

10 for 2 decimal places...
100 for 3 etc...

```
String realPoint = (string)pointPart;
```

Plus long connot hold 17 digits. it holds 10.
so you probably want a float variable

Comment: +1 but it's a style abuse of `static_cast` if you ask me, just `long(val*N)%N` will do nicely.

Comment: @spartan very good, but unfortunately it doesn't discard zeros

Comment: discard zeros? example and why?

Comment: according to this method -> val = 131414.4342424234,  pointPart = -83648 (note: I mul and div by 100,000 to get 5 spaces)